# Laravel livewire property nested binding not showing the value in the form field

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component for showing profile information. In my form, I'm binding the value to the `wire:model` as nested data. but it's not showing the value in the textbox.

**component**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Profile;

use Livewire\Component;

class BasicInfo extends Component
{
    public $user;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->user = auth()->user();

    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.profile.basic-info');
    }
}
```

**blade file**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>{{ __('Profile Information') }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" wire:model="user.name" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" wire:model="user.phone" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="location" class="form-label">Location</label>
                    <input type="text" wire:model="user.location.name" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I do `dd($user)` in the blade file it returning the user object properly.

when I directly assign the value to public property in component and reference it in the blade it is also working.

Laravel: 8.x
Livewire: 2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `wire:model` Eloquent property binding, you will need to use the `$rules` property on your component:

```
protected $rules = [
    'user.name' => 'required',
    'user.phone' => 'required',
];
```

This array sets up default validation rules for fields on your component, and acts as a whitelist for which properties can be bound to.

With regards to your `user.location.name`, Livewire currently doesn't support nesting related model fields like that. You'll need to mount that `location` into another property on your model and bind to that.

Comment: `user.location.name` also returned the expected value

Comment: if my rules are something like this: `'job.apply_type'   => 'required|' . Rule::in(['link', 'email']),`, PHP doens't allow add it in a property value? What should I do instead of?